# How to run XUnit test on both self-host & production webapi service?

Tags: testing, asp.net-web-api, xunit, fixture, self-hosting

I'd like to write a test for my ASP.NET WebApi service and run it against a self-hosted service and the live web hosted service. I imagine that this can be done with a test fixture, but I'm not sure how to set it up. Does anyone know of an example of using a configurable test fixture so that you can pass a parameter to Xunit to choose a self hosted fixture or a web hosted fixture?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it works with latest xUnit 2.0 beta.

Create a fixture:

```
public class SelfHostFixture : IDisposable {
    public static string HostBaseAddress { get; private set; }
    HttpSelfHostServer server;
    HttpSelfHostConfiguration config;

    static SelfHostFixture() {
        HostBaseAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostBaseAddress"]; // HttpClient in your tests will need to use same base address
        if (!HostBaseAddress.EndsWith("/"))
            HostBaseAddress += "/";
    }

    public SelfHostFixture() {
        if (/*your condition to check if running against live*/) {
            config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(HostBaseAddress);
            WebApiConfig.Register(config); // init your web api application
            var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
            server.OpenAsync().Wait();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        if (server != null) {
            server.CloseAsync().Wait();
            server.Dispose();
            server = null;

            config.Dispose();
            config = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then define a collection that will use that fixture. Collections are the new concept to group tests in xUnit 2.

```
[CollectionDefinition("SelfHostCollection")]
public class SelfHostCollection : ICollectionFixture<SelfHostFixture> {}
```

It serves as just a marker so has no implementation.
Now, mark tests that rely on your host to be in that collection:

```
[Collection("SelfHostCollection")]
public class MyController1Test {}

[Collection("SelfHostCollection")]
public class MyController4Test {}
```

The runner will create a single instance of your fixture when running any test from within `MyController1Test` and `MyController4Test` ensuring that your server is initiated only once per collection.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the In-Memory Server for testing your controllers, so you don't need to spin up a self-host in your unit tests.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2013/01/28/writing-tests-for-an-asp-net-webapi-service.aspx

Comment: Just FYI...when doing In-Memory testing, we need to make sure that the requests and responses go through the formatters' serialization/deserialization process to catch any issues...some info here in my very old post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kiranchalla/archive/2012/05/06/in-memory-client-amp-host-and-integration-testing-of-your-web-api-service.aspx    ... considering this, i think doing Self-host test is a better option...